# Two listboxes that group items based on a conditional MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have two listboxes set up like this in a familiar fashion:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,35,0,-32" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}" Grid.RowSpan="3" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yy}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

One listbox is for non-expired dates and it's respective and the other listbox is for expired dates and it's respective number.

I was wondering how can I adjust my conditional or property to bind correctly so that the property only binds when the condition is satisfied.

I have tried the conditional below but either all the dates (regardless of expired or not bind to the first listbox) or my properties do not bind correctly.

I would like to see an example on how to set this up.

Here's a sample of my conditional in my view model.

```
ListInformation tempList = new ListInformation();

if (DateTime.Compare(Date, DateTime.Now) > 0)
{
    Date = tempList.Date;
    Number = tempList.Number; 
}
else if (DateTime.Compare(Date, DateTime.Now) < 0)
{
    Exp_Date = tempList.Date;
    Exp_Number = tempList.Number; 
}
```

EDIT:

So, here's my current setup.

I have an xml file that gets read when a user clicks on an import button. I have a class/model that strips out all the key items from the xml and saves them into the database. I only want to display the number and date from that xml file onto my listboxs on my view. On my view, I have two listboxes... one for non-expired dates and it's number and one for expired dates and it's number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be simple enough.

Create Two Lists :

```
List<YourType> ListExpiry = new List<YourType>();
List<YourType> ListNonExpiry = new List<YourType>();
```

Then add items to it based on dates :

```
ListExpiry = YourSource.Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Now).Select(x => x)ToList();
ListNonExpiry = YourSource.Where(x => x.Date < DateTime.Now).Select(x => x)ToList();
```

**Note :**

1. YourType should be replaced with the DataType.
2. YourSource should be replaced by Source of Data.

**And in XAML :**

For First ListBox:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ListExpiry}"
```

For Second ListBox:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ListNonExpiry}"
```

**Update :**

In your MainViewModel :

```
public static List<YourType> ListExpiry = new List<YourType>();
public static List<YourType> ListNonExpiry = new List<YourType>();
```

Where you want to set the values (call it like):

```
MainViewModel.ListExpiry = .....
MainViewModel.ListNonExpiry = .....
```

In your App.xaml file :

```
<yourNamespacePrefix:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModelResource" />
```

e.g.

```
<Self:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="mainWindowViewModel" />
```

Also you need to change your dataContext in your XAML file something like :

```
<Window ............. DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModelResource}" />
```

Comment: Does this need a notify too?

Comment: Are you talking about INotifyPropertyChanged? If yes then : if your collection changes at runtime then my answer is yes else it is not necessary.

Comment: Yes my collections change at runtime. I have a question though, those are my items source but for my textblocks in my listbox, I want to add the date and number. Should those just be where I'm getting the date and number?

Comment: @Euridice01 Yes of course your xaml for TextBlocks remains same as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: For some reason, nothing binds still. I'm not sure why?

Comment: @Euridice01 Run your project. And Close it. Then go to View Menu of Visual Studio and open Output Window. Can you see any Binding Errors?

Comment: I will double check in a min. Can you see my edit just in case to see what I'm doing matches what you said. Thanks Vishal!

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong. I had the list query before I saved the items to db. It seems to be working now. Is it alright that for both of my list boxes... I have the same propery named binded? Like for example, In listbox 1, I bind Date and in listbox 2, I bind a property called Date as well (Of course, I have different itemsSource though). Thanks again.

Comment: One more question, I'm sorry... If I log in and outside of my app, the listboxes don't populate with the information that's stored until the user imports another file, then they appear. Why do you think they disappear when I reload the view?

Comment: Are you sure they disappears? Or items inside it disappears? Change the background of your ListBox to make it sure.

Comment: I don't think it's the background, it think it has something to do with the constructor? Should I call something in my constructor? I think the list is still bind but only visible when the user loads another file.

Comment: OK. Now I understood. When you log in and out of your app, the lists that you declared in C# code are declared again and so they are empty. Declare those lists in your Apps MainWindow.xaml's Constructor. Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your collection of dates is populated.

I would creat two collections and bind to them respectively. In the getter add your conditions...

```
public ICollection<listType> ExpiredDates{ get { return from p in source where p.Date < DateTime.Now select;}}
```

Then when your dates get populated, however that might be, call PropertyChanged on these properties to notify the view to update. You might need a placeholder set method too.

```
OnPropertyChanged("ExpiredDates");
```

Excuse code quality, iPads suck when coding.